# Setup a Magento cron job to call multiple models

Tags: magento, cron

I'm trying to run two models as part of a cron job.  However, the code in my config.xml is causing only one model to actually run:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <Class_Module>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>Class_Module/Foo::cronJob</model>
                <model>Class_Module/Bar::cronJob</model>
            </run>
        </Class_Module>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Is it possible to run two models from one cron schedule?  What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <something_unique_1>
            <schedule><cron_expr>01 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>Class_Module/Foo::cronJob</model></run>
        </something_unique_1>
        <something_unique_2>
            <schedule><cron_expr>01 * * * *</cron_expr></schedule>
            <run><model>Class_Module/Bar::cronJob</model></run>
        </something_unique_2>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

The XML will be parsed into an array so `something_unique_1` and `something_unique_2` will be just keys of `jobs[]` array.

Comment: I was hoping to set them with the same cron schedule, but this looks good.  Thanks!

Comment: Just don't use `* * * * *` unless you know what you are doing ;-)

Comment: LOL, that was for testing purposes.  Fail fast!