# How to set-up a cron job for multiple models in magento?

Tags: php, magento, cron

I'm trying to set-up a cron job for multiple models. I have two methods (method1 and method2) in Model (observer.php) for which I want to set cron job. My code :

**Config.xml file :**

```
 <crontab>
        <jobs>            
        <erpbridge_update>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>erpbridge/observer::method1</model>
            </run>

        </erpbridge_update>  
        <mss_erpbridge>
                <schedule>
                <cron_expr>* * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
                <run>
            <model>erpbridge/observer::method2</model>
            </run>
            </mss_erpbridge>

        </jobs>
    </crontab>
```

Name space is Mss and  module name is Erpbridge, Corn with the right module name working perfectly `<mss_erpbridge>` but this is not working `</erpbridge_update>`. When I set the same key for both `<mss_erpbridge>` then only the second works.

**My query :**

Is it possible to set a cron job for multiple Models if yes, How?

(I followed : [Setup a Magento cron job to call multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035842/setup-a-magento-cron-job-to-call-multiple-models) did't work)

Comment: it might be possible that the crons conflict, because u've set both crons every minute. try changing anyone of them

Comment: @Manashvibirla I tried by changing schedule of cron, still having the same issue :-(